# Java parallel stream to fill array

Tags: java, java-stream, java-10

I have an hashmap that is very big and it's full of prime numbers.

```
var mapA = new HashMap<Integer, Long>();
```

I need to do heavy calculations on it and so I am using parallel streams:

```
var res = new ArrayList<Integer();

mapA.entrySet()
        .parallelStream()
        .forEach( x -> {

            var values = mapA.entrySet()
                                    .parallelStream()
                                    .filter( /*conditions*/ )
                                    .map(y -> y.getKey())
                                    .toArray();                 

            Arrays.stream(values)
                      .parallel()
                      .sorted()
                      .forEach(val -> {

                           synchronized (this) {
                                res.add(x.getKey());
                                res.add((Integer) val);
                           }

                      });


        });
```

As you can see, there is `res` which is an array that is outside the scope of the stream. I need the loop to be parallel otherwise the calculation could take minutes and minutes. Is this needed?

```
.forEach(val -> {

    synchronized (this) {
        res.add(x.getKey());
        res.add((Integer) val);
    }

});
```

I have added the `synchronized` because since the stream runs in parallel, I don't want to have race conditions in case that 2 or more threads are adding data in `res` at the same time.

I have tried to remove the synchronized (this) and the program still works fine. But how can I be sure that it will always work fine?

Thank you

---

I am going to add here the entire code if needed:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class DiffieHellman {

    private static final int LIMIT = 65536;

    private final long p;
    private final long g;

    public DiffieHellman(long p, long g) {
        this.p = p;
        this.g = g;
    }

    public List<Integer> tryBruteForce(long publicA, long publicB) {
        List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        var mapA = new HashMap<Integer, Long>(
                IntStream
                        .rangeClosed(0, LIMIT)
                        .parallel()
                        .boxed()
                        .collect(
                                Collectors.toMap(x -> x, x -> DiffieHellmanUtils.modPow(publicB, x, p))
                        )
        );

        var mapB = new HashMap<Integer, Long>(
                IntStream
                        .rangeClosed(0, LIMIT)
                        .parallel()
                        .boxed()
                        .collect(
                                Collectors.toMap(x -> x, x -> DiffieHellmanUtils.modPow(publicB, x, p))
                        )
        );

        mapA.entrySet()
                    .parallelStream()
                    .forEach( x -> {

                        var values = mapB.entrySet()
                                        .parallelStream()
                                        .filter( y -> y.getValue().equals(x.getValue()))
                                        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                                        .toArray(Integer[]::new);

                        Arrays.stream(values)
                                .parallel()
                                .sorted()
                                .forEach(val -> {
                                        res.add(x.getKey());
                                        res.add((Integer) val);
                                });


                    });

        return res;
    }

}
```

Comment: I really doubt using `synchronized` with `parallelStream` is a good idea though. Or even in general if operations are atomic in nature I would preferably use a data structure much more suited and close to my requirements.

Comment: I have the same doubt but I'd like to not have this doubt!

Comment: @HadiJ I have updated the code, I forgot to paste the code, values is just an array of Integers!

Comment: in the array named 'res' is the inserted key and value must be sequenced ?

Comment: @BurakAkyıldız yes

Comment: I really really feel, you should share the exact use case for which you're creating this huge puzzle. Few things right away - 1. What kind of similarity does the `filter` bring in to add two keys of the `Map`?  2. Why do you need to sort data while iterating within and then add value from another collection altogether to the result list.?

Comment: I have added the entrire class code

Comment: Isn't `res.add(x.getKey());
                                        res.add((Integer) val);` adding the same value twice? Since `x` is the `entrySet()` and `val` is after forming the stream of `Map.Entry::getKey`!

Comment: Yes, that's required by the task I need to accomplish

Comment: Can you please share an example with a sample input and output expected and (if possible) the reason why you need to do it using `parallelStream`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturally, you can simply use a synchronized collection like other answers pointed out, but this might not be performant enough due to contention and is still quite cumbersome to write.

Instead, you could approach the problem in a slightly different way by using Stream API idiomatically.

Firstly, nested operations can be done in a single stream pipeline:

```
mapB.entrySet()
            .parallelStream()
            .filter(y -> y.getValue().equals(x.getValue()))
            .map(y -> y.getKey())
            .sorted()
            .forEach(val -> {

                synchronized (this) {
                    res.add(x.getKey());
                    res.add((Integer) val);
                }
            });
```

Secondly, in order to avoid concurrency issues, the easiest way would be to drop the imperative approach and leverage Stream API's declarativeness.

In order to do that, one would not manually `for-each` and then `add` elements to the result but let Stream manage that.

What you want to do here is to create a new sequence by replacing each element of `mapA` entrySet() with a custom sequence:

```
List<Integer> res = mapA.entrySet()
      .parallelStream()
      .flatMap(x -> mapB.entrySet().stream()
         .filter(y -> y.getValue().equals(x.getValue()))
         .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
         .sorted()
         .flatMap(v -> Stream.of(x.getKey(), v)))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Nested `parallelStream` can be omitted since `flatMap` is calling `sequential()` on a Stream anyway.